# What is the difference between "Qed" and "Defined"?

Tags: scope, coq

In the interactive theorem prover Coq, any interactive proof or definition can be terminated with either `Qed` or `Defined`. There is some concept of "opacity" which `Qed` enforces but `Defined` does not.  For instance, the book *Certified Programming with Dependent Types*, by Adam Chlipala, [states](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Subset.html#pred_strong4):

> We end the "proof" with `Defined` instead of `Qed`, so that the definition we constructed remains visible. This contrasts to the case of ending a proof with `Qed`, where the details of the proof are hidden afterward. (More formally, `Defined` marks an identifier as *transparent*, allowing it to be unfolded; while `Qed` marks an identifier as *opaque*, preventing unfolding.)

However, I'm not quite sure what this means in practice.  There is a later [example](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/GeneralRec.html#lengthOrder) in which it is necessary to use `Defined` due to the need for `Fix` to inspect the structure of a certain proof, but I don't understand exactly what this "inspection" entails, or why it would fail if `Qed` were used instead.  (Looking at the definition of `Fix` wasn't exactly enlightening either).

Superficially, it's hard to tell what `Qed` is actually doing.  For instance, if I write:

```
Definition x : bool.
exact false.
Qed.
```

I can still see the value of `x` by executing the command `Print x.`  In addition, I'm allowed later to pattern-match on the "opaque" value of `x`:

```
Definition not_x : bool :=
  match x with
    | true => false
    | false => true
  end.
```

Therefore it seems like I'm able to use the value of `x` just fine.  What does Prof. Chlipala mean by "unfolding" here?  What exactly is the difference between an opaque and a transparent difference?  Most importantly, what is special about `Fix` that makes this matter?

Comment: If you make something opaque, you won't be able to perform delta-reduction on it. "Unfolding" is performing delta-reduction on a specific definition. If `x` is transparent, `not_x` evaluates to `true`. If `x` is opaque, `not_x` evaluates to `if x then false else true`. Use the command `Eval lazy in not_x`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not really able to use the value of `x`, but only its type. For example, since `x` is `false`, try to prove that `x = false` or that `x = true`, and you won't be able to. You can unfold the definition of `not_x` (its definition is the same as that of `x`, but using `Defined`), but you won't be able to inspect the value of `x`, you only know that it is a boolean.

```
Lemma not_x_is_true : not_x = true.
Proof.
unfold not_x. (* this one is fine *)
unfold x. (* This one is not. Error: Cannot coerce x to an evaluable reference. *)
```

The idea behind `Qed` vs `Defined` is that in some cases, you don't want to look at the content of proof term (because it is not relevant, or just a really huge term you don't want to unfold), and all you need to know is that the statement is true, not why it is true. In the end, the question you have to ask before using `Qed` or `Defined` is: Do I need to know *why* one theorem is true, or do I only need to know that it is true?

Comment: Okay, I see now what the difference is (and that `unfold` meant the tactic—oops!).  Do you have any insight about `Fix`, since that's the part I was really hoping to understand?  How can a function like `Fix` unfold (or attempt to unfold) one of its arguments?

Comment: I don't remember exactly how it works, so maybe you should move such particular question to the Coq-Club mailing list. From what I remember, a fixpoint will only reduce if its argument starts with a constructor. For example, ``plus (S n) m`` will reduce to ``S (plus n m)`` but ``plus n (S m)`` will never reduce without destructing ``n`` first (usually by induction since it's a fixpoint) because the fixpoint inspects the first argument of ``plus``. I can't remember if delta reduction (unfolding of definition) is performed on the argument of a fixpoint, prior to that test.

Comment: I was actually discussing the `Fix` combinator from the [`Wf`](http://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Wf.html) (well-foundedness) library, not the builtin `fix`.  Thank you for your help though!

Comment: It's quite close in fact. ``Fix`` is a fixpoint (so build using ``fix``) built on top of the ``Acc_inv`` lemma. If you were to ``Qed`` this lemma, you would never be able to unfold or perform induction on ``Fix`` because its body would be opaque. By ``Defined`` the proof of ``Acc_inv``, you allow yourself to have a look at the proof term, and so you will be able to reason on the body of ``Fix``.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks again for the enlightening comments.